# Why are the logical reads appearing in IO STATISTICS even after cleaning various caches?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to understand the output of IO STATISTICS in sql server (2014) and using AdventureWorks as the database.

Here is the code

```
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE('ALL')
DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
DBCC FLUSHPROCINDB(7)
CHECKPOINT
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS

SET STATISTICS TIME ON
SET STATISTICS IO ON
SELECT * FROM [HumanResources].[Employee]
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
SET STATISTICS IO OFF
```

The output is

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

(290 row(s) affected)
Table 'Employee'. Scan count 1, **logical reads 9**, **physical reads 1**, read-ahead reads 7, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 15 ms,  elapsed time = 105 ms.

Even after cleaning all the caches and buffers, why is not logical read coming out to be 0 and physical read coming out to be 10 (1 already mentioned + 9 pages of logical read)? My understanding of the logical read is the number of pages read from data cache (in other words the cache of data of tables in sql server).

Answer (score 2):

All page reads are read from pages in the buffer pool and are logical reads.

The single physical read means the query only had to wait for a single page to be read in from disc to the buffer pool.

The remainder were read in by the [read ahead mechanism](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191475(v=sql.105).aspx) and were already in the cache by the time the query needed them.

That still leaves a single page discrepancy as 7 plus 1 is 8 not 9. Possibly the mechanism here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ialonso/2011/12/09/the-read-ahead-that-doesnt-count-as-read-ahead/